# storage or overwrite a value to a specific key python

Tags: python, dictionary, input, terminal, output

I am new at Python programming and have a little problem at the moment. In other words, I am trying to make an output (print()) where the saved value (which was chosen from input) with the correct key will show in the Terminal.

This is what I have already written. I hope it will help you to understand my problem :D

```
if request_filename in dictionary_main:
        new_mark = input('What is the new number which should be saved to the filename?: ')
        print('Your saved work: ' + str(request_filename) + 'Mark: ' + str(dictionary_main[request_filename]))
        print('---------Changes has been saved---------')
```

All in all, I want to save a value to a key and then I want to show both of them (key and value) in the console like:

"key is value" or so

In advance, thank you for help! :)

Comment: Your question would probably be clearer if you created a [mre] with a simple, clear description of what you want to accomplish. There is a lot of irrelevant code here, it makes it hard to understand what exactly your problem is.

Comment: oh ok sorry I am going to change the question and make it better understandable

Comment: is it now better? LG

Comment: Is `request_filename` a type of `dict` rather than `str`? I'm wondering the code example will work or not.

Comment: request_filename = input('Enter filename please: ')  --> that should a input for user .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the return from `input` function shall be `str`.

Comment: No problem :)  Yea but I want a number from the user which should be added to an available Key. If you know what I mean

Comment: Or are they some different things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can manipulate the dictionary object using its key.

For example:

```py
BASKET = {
   'apple': 1,
   'banana': 2
}

print(f"There is {BASKET['apple']} apple in basket") # There is 1 apple in basket

# update banana's value
BASKET['banana'] = 1
print(f"There is {BASKET['banana']} banana in basket") # There is 1 banana in basket
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer Divik :) But now I want to add a value to an Key. How can I do that?

Comment: @MartinLackner you can also create a key just using `str` as key like the above code.
Like `BASKET['orange'] =2` will create a key `orange` and store its value as `2`.

Comment: Ohhh i know now ... I think ... I am going to test it. Can i reply you back if I have still trouble?

Comment: Sure.  You can raise another question in StackOverflow if it's not relevent to this one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now the code works as intended. I wish you a nice evening and see you ;) :D :)